# Remove row from dataframe with identique colname in other dataframe in R

Tags: r, row

I have df1:

```
Name A B D
1
2
3
4
```

I have df2

```
Type Cow Cat Dog
A
B
C
D
```

I want to remove the row from df2 of which i have no column in df1. In this case i have no column C in df1 so i want to remove row C from df2.

Expected output

```
Type Cow Cat Dog
A
B
D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df2[df2$type %in% intersect(colnames(df1), df2$type), ]
```